# Recording Video with PyQt5 QMediaRecorder

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtmultimedia, qmediarecorder

I'm developing an interface with PyQt. I want to record a video with QMediaRecorder when the button is pressed. I would be glad if you could help.

```
def openCameraFunction(self):
    self.cameraName = self.availableCameras[self.cameraSelector.currentIndex()].description()
    print(self.cameraName)
    self.camera = QCamera(self.availableCameras[self.cameraSelector.currentIndex()])
    # self.viewFinder.setMediaObject(self.camera)
    self.camera.setViewfinder(self.viewFinder)
    self.camera.setCaptureMode(QCamera.CaptureVideo)
    self.camera.error.connect(lambda: self.cameraAlertFunction(self.camera.errorString()))
    self.camera.start()
    self.filePath = 0

def saveVideoFunction(self):
    path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Video Kaydet")
    if path:
        self.savePath = path
        self.recorder = QMediaRecorder(self.camera)
        self.recorder.record(os.path.join(self.savePath, "Deneme.avi" ))
```